# Unable to install scipy package in anaconda

Tags: python

My problem is that I want to use the package scipy in Spyder IDE(in Anaconda Navigator).

I tried to install this package with this code but this gives me an error.

```
conda install -c anaconda scipy
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: What's the error it gives?

Comment: It would also help to know where you tried to run this code

Comment: It gives me the error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Anaconda3\\Library\\resources\\icudtl.dat'

Comment: I tried the command in the Anaconda Prompt

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using version 3, try this option..

conda install -c scipy

Comment: It does not work,gives me the error "too few arguments"

Comment: Should I close the Anaconda Navigator first?

Comment: from command prompt (windows) or terminal (mac) try without -c  it works..